# Iteration of a recurrence solution in R

Tags: r, matrix, iteration, linear-algebra, recurrence

I'm given a question in R language to find the 30th term of the recurrence relation `x(n) = 2*x(n-1) - x(n-2)`, where x(1) = 0 and `x(2) = 1`. I know the answer is 29 from mathematical deduction. But as a newbie to R, I'm slightly confused by how to make things work here. The following is my code:

```
loop <- function(n){
  a <- 0
  b <- 1
  for (i in 1:30){
    a <- b
    b <- 2*b - a
  }
  return(a)
}

loop(30)
```

I'm returned 1 as a result, which is way off.

In case you're wondering why this looks Python-ish, I've mostly only been exposed to Python programming thus far (I'm new to programming in general). I've tried to check out all the syntax in R, but I suppose my logic is quite fixed by Python. Can someone help me out in this case? In addition, does R have any resources like PythonTutor to help visualise the code execution logic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it another couple of ways.

1. Solve the linear homogeneous recurrence relation, let

> x(n) = r^n

plugging into the recurrence relation, you get the quadratic

> r^n-2*r^(n-1)+r^(n-2) = 0

, i.e.,

> r^2-2*r+1=0

, i.e.,

> r = 1, 1

leading to general solution

> x(n) = c1 * 1^n + c2 * n * 1^n = c1 + n * c2

and with x(1) = 0 and x(2) = 1, you get c2 = 1, c1 = -1, s.t.,

> x(n) = n - 1
>
> => x(30) = 29

Hence, R code to compute x(n) as a function of n is trivial, as shown below:

```
x <- function(n) {
   return (n-1)
}
x(30)
#29
```

2. Use matrix powers (first find the following matrix A from the recurrence relation):

   [image: [x(n) x(n-1)]' = []

(The matrix A has algebraic / geometric multiplicity, its corresponding eigenvectors matrix is singular, otherwise you could use spectral decomposition yourself for fast computation of matrix powers, here we shall use the library `expm` as shown below)

```
library(expm)

A <- matrix(c(2,1,-1,0), nrow=2)

A %^% 29 %*% c(1,0)  # [x(31) x(30)]T = A^29.[x(2) x(1)]T
#      [,1]
# [1,]   30  # x(31)
# [2,]   29  # x(30)

# compute x(n)
x <- function(n) {
    (A %^% (n-1) %*% c(1,0))[2]
}
x(30)
# 29
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need might be something like below

```
loop <- function(n){
  if (n<=2) return(n-1)
  a <- 0
  b <- 1
  for (i in 3:n){
    a_new <- b
    b <- 2*b - a
    a <- a_new
  }
  return(b)
}
```

then

```
> loop(30)
[1] 29
```

---

If you need a recursion version, below is one realization

```
loop <- function(n) {
  if (n<=2) return(n-1)
  2*loop(n-1)-loop(n-2)
}
```

which also gives

```
> loop(30)
[1] 29
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the variable you're iterating on in the loop, so nothing is updating.

```
loop <- function(n){
  a <- 0
  b <- 1
  for (i in 1:30){
    a <- b
    b <- 2*i - a
  }
  return(a)
}
```

Comment: It's a recurrence relation.  The loop variable isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a recursive function.

```
f <- function(x, n) {
  n <- 1:n
  r <- function(n) {
    if (length(n) == 2) x[2]
    else r({
      x <<- c(x[2], 2*x[2] - x[1])
      n[-1]
    })
  }
  r(n)
}

x <- c(0, 1)
f(x, 30)
# [1] 29
```